# Methods } expected

Tags: c#, methods

Got the following code giving first error of '} expected'

Just trying to get and print student data. Not sure if I need to make these methods like a return type or something. Any advice welcome, Thank you.

```
namespace studentInfo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            getUserInformation();
            printStudentDetails(string firstName, string lastName, string birthday);
        }

        static void getUserInformation()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the student's first name: ");
            string firstName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the student's last name");
            string lastName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your bithdate");
            //DateTime birthdate = Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine());
            string birthday = Console.ReadLine();

        }

        static void printStudentDetails(string firstName, string lastName, string birthday)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} was born on: {2}", firstName, lastName, birthday);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Puhhh there is a major leak of understanding. You better try to understand the basics like, methods and argument passing before going more deeper.

Comment: That's not very helpful. I have read about this but putting into practice takes some practice, which is what I am attempting to do now, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

you are calling a method incorrectly:

```
 printStudentDetails(string firstName, string lastName, string birthday);
```

should be:

```
 printStudentDetails(firstName, lastName, birthday);
```

You also must have defined vars, firstName,lastName,birthday, before passing them to your method.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it wrong mate!

You just need the variables to call method..you do not require its datatypes.

so it should be like :-

```
printStudentDetails(firstName, lastName, birthday);
```

and if you want to use the variales like this then declare them globally like :-

```
public static dynamic firstName;
    public static dynamic lastName;
    public static dynamic birthday;

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    getUserInformation();
    printStudentDetails(firstName, lastName, birthday);
}

static void getUserInformation()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the student's first name: ");
    firstName = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the student's last name");
    lastName = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter your bithdate");
    birthday = Console.ReadLine();

}

static void printStudentDetails(string firstName, string lastName, string birthday)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} was born on: {2}", firstName, lastName, birthday);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Right! Yeah off course. The call to printStudentDetails just passes in the arguments but the actual method needs to define the variable type in the parameter list. Why doesn't the method know what the variable types being passed in are? I mean, they have been declared globally, so why do we need to reaffirm their types in the method parameter list? Also, I have changed the code, as per your suggestions, but am getting an error on the arguments passed in printStudentDetails( firstName, lastName, birthday);. It says 'An object reference is required for the non-static files, method, or property

Comment: well you can even use dynamic or object  if you dont want to specify the datatype in method parameters but you cant put blank! @user2036750 check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14281289/passing-type-var-into-a-method-in-c-sharp

Comment: So, nearly there I think.

Comment: ok, please accept as answer if you think its useful @user2036750